.NET 6 Connect to sql server on IIS (window server)
I have a sql server and IIS service running on Window Server 2019. I wrote some API populating the data in database in the BE code which is located in the IIS site folder.
In the appsettings.json file I set the connection strings as below:
Server=myServerIpAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
My API still works fine if I open the port 1433 in the firewall but as I read some cautions, it could lead to some serious security issue.
I've tried set the connection strings like: Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True; without opening the port but my API doesn't work anymore.
May I have some solutions for this issue?

Are yo saying you opened port 1433 to the outside world? No, you should not be doing that. The API's port should be open, but not SQL Server's. Then people connect to that API and the API can talk to SQL Server (as they are within the same lcoal network). If, however, you mean that port 1433 was open to local traffic, that's normal.

What address does localhost resolve to on the machine? Possibly it's resolving to the IPv6 address ::1 instead of the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 - and if SQL Server is only configured to listen on IPv4 sockets then you won't be able to connect with ::1. Via the SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager tool check the Server Protocols configuration for your instance to see which protocols are enabled and which addresses and ports TCP/IP (in particular) is listening on. It would be very unusual for it to be listening on an assigned address but not 127.0.0.1.

@ThomA yes I've tried opening port but it's so dangerous, what if the people connecting are not in the same network? I've not found and idea with that

The people out side of the network, as I stated, interact with your API, not the SQL Server.

@AlwaysLearning the localhost resolve to the ::1, I will have a try

If it's a localhost connection, you should be using . anyway.

@ThomA Thanks for your advice, so do I need to disable the  **Allow remote connections to this server options and configure the firewall in the server right? Because my API code and the sql server are in the same server

If all connections are from the localhost (so you also develop on the localhost) you don't need TCP/IP enabled, no. If you develop from a different host (which presumably you do), you would need TCP/IP enabled still, so you can connect to the SQL Server from your PC from the local domain.

@ThomA yeah I develop in my own machine and try to deploy to the IIS, actually I want anyone could call my API but not able to remote to my sql server

Which I address in my prior comments, @cryspijohnny . What was unclear about them?

@ThomA ah no, just my own thought, nevermind. Really appreciate your advice!
